# Laravel 5 with Charts4php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, charts, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5 with  ChartsPHP to render a chart but I'm getting this error. I have also moved all required files into the public resources folder.
[Documentation](http://www.chartphp.com/how-to-create-donut-chart-php/) titorial I'm following

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\chartphp' not found
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/chartphp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/js/chartphp.css">

    <style>
        /* white color data labels */
        .jqplot-data-label{color:white;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:40%; min-width:450px;">
    {{$out}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \View as View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
include("lib/inc/chartphp_dist.php");

public function Test(){

        $p = new chartphp();
        $p->data = array(array(array('a',6), array('b',8), array('c',14), array('d',20)));
        $p->chart_type = "donut";
        $p->title = "Donut Chart";
         $out = $p->render('c1');
         return view('pages.test')->with('out', $out);
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('test', 'RequestController@Test');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace of chartphp isn't correct. Try `new \chartphp();`